# Permission Denied when trying to read file w/644 permission

Tags: linux, permissions

I am trying to write a PHP script for a Web server (lighttpd) to read a file in another user. 
The Web server runs under user http:

```
http      1929   336  0 Nov20 /usr/bin/lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
```

The file the script is trying to read has the following permissions:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi www-data 721 Oct 30 05:20 /home/pi/bmSunday
```

Which I thought meant that any user can read it.

The fopen in the script results in a Permission denied:

```
Warning: fopen(/home/pi/bmSunday): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /srv/http/p1/index.php
```

I am running Arch Linux.

```
uname -r
```

displays:

```
4.4.32-2-ARCH
```

What permissions do I need to set on the file so that user http is allowed to read it?

By the way, am I correct in assuming I can also test the permission via:

```
sudo -u http cat /home/pi/bmSunday
```

Using the above command, the result is:

```
cat: /home/pi/bmSunday: Permission denied
```

Comment: Check the permissions on `/home/pi`, make sure it has world-execute permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions on the directory are probably wrong, `http` probably doesn't have execute permission. Add world execute permissions:

```
chmod o+x /home/pi
```

Answer (score 0):

You (as a user) in your example have no execute permissions. So yes chmod +x file. Keep in mind this adds execute to both users others.

Answer (score 0):

If you give all other user execute permission on home directory of other users it compromise security to all other user. it will be better if you give permission only http user by acl.

$ setfacl -m u:http:r-x /home/pi